# Pushing commit to github repository throwing error

Tags: github, git-bash, git-push

The error I am getting:

```
To https://github.com/Git-Username/Repo.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/user/repo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Command I am executing:

```
git push origin master
```

I have tried nearly everything when I googled this error, I tried pulling etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried pulling etc.

pulling should have been enough to solve the issue.

But if your local history is correct (`git log`), and you are the only one pushig to that repository, you could also simply force push

```
git push --force -u origin master
```

That will override the history on the remote.

Comment: You are a legend, thank you so much for this, I've been trying to learn git for a while but a lot of the communities I contact are no help, you are a king!